# Update Checkin of User's Location not working Properly using QuickBlox in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

When I am Updating One of My checkins of User's Location by QuickBlox Location Module using Following QuickBlox Code :

```
QBLGeoData *geodata = [QBLGeoData geoData];  
    geodata.ID = 34638;  
    geodata.latitude = 13.2344;  
    geodata.longitude = -42.23523;  
    geodata.status = @"I'am at Pizzzza house!";

    [QBLocation updateGeoData:geodata delegate:self]; 

    pragma mark -
    pragma mark QBActionStatusDelegate

    -(void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{  
        // Update checkin result  
        if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBLGeoDataResult.class]){  
            QBLGeoDataResult *checkinResult = (QBLGeoDataResult *)result;  
            NSLog(@"Checkin: %@", checkinResult.geoData);  
        }else{  
            NSLog(@"errors=%@", result.errors);  
        }  
    }
```

It provides me these values in NSLog for latitude and longitude:
latitude:13.000000
longitude:-42.000000
where as I need the actual Values Which is
latitude:13.2344
longitude:-42.23523

While Creating Checkin's For First Time it creates user Checkin Properly  but while UpDating User Location's Checkin , it makes all the Values to Zero(0) after Decimal. 
I also tried this thing :

```
 QBLGeoData *geodata = [QBLGeoData geoData];  
    geodata.ID = 34638;  
    geodata.latitude = 13.2344 * 10000;  
    geodata.longitude = -42.23523 *100000;  
    geodata.status = @"I'am at Pizzzza house!";

    [QBLocation updateGeoData:geodata delegate:self];
```

and there after retrieving these values and dividing it but it Shows me Error that:
"Latitude must be less than or equal to 90",
"Longitude must be greater than or equal to -180"
So,Can anybody please Help Me Out...as I am Stucked up Over Here..,
Your Help would be Highly Appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.